# When i run the program, i only get the default result. Even though the input number isint in that range

Tags: go, switch-statement

Program is supposed to output a string, based on the number inputted. Whatever i input in, i always get the default case

Tried  using an if condition too. Didnt work

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var grade int
    fmt.Print("Input your grade:")
    fmt.Scan(&grade)
    gradeInLetters(grade)
}

const maxScore = 100

func gradeInLetters(s int) {
    switch {
    case maxScore < 100 && maxScore > 90:
            fmt.Println("Grade A")

    case maxScore < 90 && maxScore > 80:
        fmt.Println("Grade B")

    case maxScore < 80 && maxScore > 70:
        fmt.Println("Grade C")

    case maxScore < 70 && maxScore > 60:
        fmt.Println("Grade D")

    default:
        fmt.Println("Grade F")
    }
}
```

Should output the string, based on the grade given

Answer (score 2):

There's no case that matches. `maxScore` is defined as a constant `100`, and the closest case to matching is this one:

```
case maxScore < 100 && maxScore > 90:
```

But, of course, 100 is *not* "less than 100"; it *is* 100. You probably meant:

```
case maxScore <= 100 && maxScore > 90:
```

Which would match, because 100 *is* "less than or equal to" 100.

The bigger problem is that your input is passed into the function as the argument `s`, which isn't used anywhere in the function body; all your comparisons are against the constant `maxScore`, which is probably not what you intended. What you really probably wanted is:

```
case s <= maxScore && s > 90:
```

... or something along those lines - it's not really clear what the intended purpose of `maxScore` is.

Comment: You'll also want to look over each of those checks - the ranges are all exclusive so scores of exactly 90, 80, or 70 will all also hit the `default` case.